# Does alignas affect the value of sizeof?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    alignas(double) unsigned char c[1024];   // array of characters, suitably aligned for doubles
    alignas(16) char d[100];            // align on 16 byte boundary
    cout<<sizeof(c)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(d)<<endl;
    constexpr int n = alignof(int);     // ints are aligned on n byte boundarie
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
```

Here is the code, for `alignas(double) unsigned char c[1024];`, it means the `c` should be aligned by `double`, the `double` is `8` bytes.
So I think `sizeof(c)` should be `1024*8` bytes, but the console output is `1024`.

So I am confused. Who can tell me the reason?

Comment: how do you figure 1024*8 ? (the alignment is for the array start, not for every individual array member)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `alignas` keyword can be used to dictate alignment requirements. `alignas(double)` for example forces the variable to have the same alignment requirements as a `double`. On my platform, this will mean that the variable is aligned on 8 byte boundaries.

In your example, the whole array will get the alignment requirements so it's being aligned on 8 byte boundaries but this won't affect its size.

It is however possible that `alignas` changes the size of a composite data type when upholding the alignment requirements requires additional padding. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct Test
{
    char a;
    alignas(double) char b;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test test;
    std::cout << "Size of Struct: " << sizeof(Test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of 'a': " << sizeof(test.a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of 'b': " << sizeof(test.b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset of 'a': " << (int)offsetof(struct Test, a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset of 'b': " << (int)offsetof(struct Test, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of Struct: 16
Size of 'a': 1
Size of 'b': 1
Offset of 'a': 0
Offset of 'b': 8
```

The size of this structure is 16 bytes on my platform even though both members are just 1 byte in size each. So `b` didn't become bigger because of the alignment requirement but there is additional padding after `a`. You can see this by looking at the size and offset of the individual members. `a` is just 1 byte in size but `b`, due to our alignment requirements, starts after a 8 byte offset.

And the size of a struct must be a multiple of its alignment, otherwise arrays don't work. So if you set an alignment requirement that's bigger than the whole struct was to begin with (for example a struct containing only a single short and you apply alignas(double) to that data member), padding must be added after it.

Comment: And the size of a struct must be a multiple of its alignment, otherwise arrays don't work. So if you set an alignment requirement that's bigger than the whole struct was to begin with (for example a struct containing only a single `short` and you apply `alignas(double)` to that data member), padding must be added after it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the C++ standard document I found I couldn't find any mention of the effect on `alignas()` on the size of an object (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), but according to my experiment (on g++ 8.3, Amd64 at least) **it does seem to affect it**.

```
struct UnalignedStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

struct alignas(512) AlignedStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(UnalignedStruct) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(AlignedStruct) << std::endl;
}
```

the output is

```
12
512
```

As it seems, it has an effect on the `sizeof()` value.

Answer (score 2):

The alignment requirement affects the whole object that it is specified for, - in this case, an array `[1024]` of char. So, the whole array gets alligned to 8 bytes, like it was shifted by a few bytes in memory as a whole, but its size remains 1024 bytes.

Comment: You means that the array `c` is aligned by `8` bytes, just means every `8` bytes is a group.

Comment: There are no groups, the alignment affects at what memory locations the variable can be stored. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) quite a bit of information on what memory alignment is.